# Replacing text with an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So I have a line of code in which I want to replace all specific codes with a an image. I have it working fine with strings but when I try to enter a code I have issues.

```
$('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html().replace(/(0)/g, '<img src="/Content/Images/mana/0.png" />'));
```

If the (0) was a word, it would work fine, but it's replacing every single 0 in the document. Is there a way to force it to recognise the brackets as part of the string? I tried enclosing them in quotation marks but I have the same problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide jsfiddle for that

Comment: `.replace(/\(0\)/g` ???

Comment: you use {{0}} intend of (0) in your html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets.

```
$('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html().replace(/\(0\)/g, '<img src="/Content/Images/mana/0.png" />'));
```

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes because SO is being daft :-)